# Bulk hostname movement to desired OU

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory

I am having a script for moving hostnames to particular OU.

gc .\list.txt |ForEach-Object { Get-ADComputer $_ | move-adobject -targetpath "" }

In above script actually am having 150 hostnames and needs to move different different ou. How we can do that.

example.

```
masuadfl01  --   move to  masu/branches/laptops
masufgd002  --   move to  masu/branches/desktops
abdufghd001  --  move to  abdu/branches/desktops
```

Like above everything should move automatically correct OU. How we can create a script like that.

If it is desktop last before digit D will be there. For laptop L will be.

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more overhead here, but you can use regex for this

First, set the regex

```
# will match a d,l,D or L character before the digit
[regex]$regex = "[dlDL](?=\d)"
```

Then you can loop through your list of hostnames

```
Get-Content -Path .\list.txt | ForEach-Object {
    
    # check if the hostname matches the regex
    $match = $regex.Match($_)
    
    # get the desired OU, first 4 characters
    $desiredOU = $_.Substring(0,4)

    If($match.Success){
        # if client is L -> move to laptops
        If($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "L"){
            Write-Host "$_ is a laptop" -ForegroundColor Green
            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=laptops,OU=branches,OU=$desiredOU,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
        # if client is D -> move to desktops
        }Elseif($match.Value.ToUpper() -eq "D"){
            Write-Host "$_ is a desktop" -ForegroundColor Green
            Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=desktops,OU=branches,OU=$desiredOU,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
        }Else{
            Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }Else{
        Write-Host "$_ not a laptop nor desktop" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, Every L should be in laptopsbut we have to check first 4 letters as well.in my example also masu means go to masu ou abdu means go to abdu ou..   As per your code Every L will go to same ou right sir.    Your help is appreciating.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a text file with only computernames listed, I would create a CSV file for this with two columns.
The first column has the computer name and the second column contains the **DistinguishedName** of the OU to move the computer to.

```
"ComputerName","Destination"
"masuadfl01","OU=laptops,OU=branches,OU=masu,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
"masufgd002","OU=desktops,OU=branches,OU=masu,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
"abdufghd001","OU=desktops,OU=branches,OU=abdu,DC=Contoso,DC=com"
```

Then your code could be like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\File.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer $_.ComputerName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $_.Destination
}
```

---

**Edit**

If there is a certain constant strategy involved in the computernames, then you can utilize that to determine the destination OU and you don't have to create a CSV file.
For instance: if all computer names start with either `masu` od `abdu` and that is the name of one of the sub OU's, you can user that as variable.
As for desktops or laptops, each name has either an `l` or a `d` character the final number and if that indeed says it is either a laptop or a desktop computer, we can use that to make the OU's distinghuished name complete:

```
# create a template OU distinguished name string
$targetOU = "OU={0},OU=branches,OU={1},DC=Contoso,DC=com"

Get-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\ComputerNamesFile.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $subOU = $_.Substring(0,4)
    if ($_ -match '([ld])\d+$') { 
        $type = switch ($matches[1]) {
            'l'  { 'laptops'; break }
            'd'  { 'desktops' }
        }
        $moveTo = $targetOU -f $type, $subOU
        Get-ADComputer $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $moveTo
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Cannot determine the computertype for '$_'"
    }
}
```

Comment: By default it will be in computers right. I needs to move all hostnames in different OU. not to same ou. more than 55 OU is there, instead of giving this complete destination name , can we use any if or for loop and make it easy script...

Comment: @Masyood That is why you need a csv, so you can map each computer to its new destination OU

Comment: OK. Thank you so much for your efforts.  We have daily more than 150 hostnames to move. and will be more than 55 OU,s so we have to do manual work right for making excel. or can we ease it any other technique.

Comment: @Masyood If there is a certain constant strategy involved in the computernames, then you can utilize that to deternmine the destination OU. Like if they all start with either `masu` od `abdu` and that is the name of one of the OU's, you can user that as variable. As for desktops or laptops, I can see there is an `l` or a `d` in each name just before the final number. Is that by chance or does that really denote the machine type?